# Is there a simpler way to translate numbers into strings?

Tags: r, vector, lambda

`a` is a vector in R

```
> a <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1)
```

that I want to "translate" into a (temporary) vector of strings so that `1` becomes `"foo"`, `2` becomes `"bar"` and `3` becomes `"baz"`.

I can achieve this with `sapply`:

```
> sapply(a, function(x) {if (x==1) return ('foo'); if (x==2) return ('bar'); return ('baz')})

[1] "foo" "bar" "baz" "baz" "bar" "baz" "foo" "bar" "foo"
```

However, I think there should be an alternative way to do this without (what I perceive as misusing) `sapply`. Is this the case?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why this answer and not (first) mine?

Comment: Both answers are correct and I had to choose one. It seemed that using a one liner fits my goal of going for a temporary assignment better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try:

```
c("foo","bar","baz")[a]
#[1] "foo" "bar" "baz" "baz" "bar" "baz" "foo" "bar" "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another obvious solution is to treat the data as factors:

```
factor(a, c(1, 2, 3), c("foo", "bar", "baz"))
# [1] foo bar baz baz bar baz foo bar foo
# Levels: foo bar baz
```

Wrap with `as.character` for the character representation:

```
as.character(factor(a, c(1, 2, 3), c("foo", "bar", "baz")))
# [1] "foo" "bar" "baz" "baz" "bar" "baz" "foo" "bar" "foo"
```